# PowerShell Multithreading and Custom Functions

Tags: multithreading, powershell, progress-bar

I have the problem that my Progressbar(Gui made with WPF) is freezing when I call a function.
I tired to solve the problem with start-job, but when I do it like that, I can't call a custom made function. I have found the paramter InitializationScript which allows me to use my functions.

But is there a better way to do it?

Thanks for your help